# How to add ellipses on a UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, ellipsis

I need to restrict number of lines in a `UITextView` to 2 and add ellipses to any overflowing text. How would I do that? For some implementation reasons I cannot use `UILabel`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do that by setting the properties of the `textContainer` like so:

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

Comment: If the size of the view is right textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail is enough.